# Cognos Report Studio OLAP Filtering

Tags: report, business-intelligence, olap, cognos, olap-cube

I'm trying to optimize a report with a crosstab in congnos report studio that has an OLAP source.

I would like to filter the cube with a prompt with multiple values.

I'm using a slicer with a formula like this

```
set( [DS_PC_Mayorista].[Delegado Comercial].[Delegado Comercial]->?DELEGADO?)
```

But it don't seems to make the report faster. Is this the correct way of filtering an OLAP source report with a crosstab in Cognos Report Studio?

Answer (score 2):

A slicer will isolate specific intersections in the data but won't necessarily filter it. You will end up with null values for intersections that don't match your criteria but the non-matching dimensional members will still be represented. Due to this, I rarely use slicers. Instead I replace my level data item with an expression that isolates the value(s) I care about. That can take the form of a set expression or simply a MUN if I only want one member worth of data. All measures will then automatically reflect only the values from the subset.

In your case, it looks like you are passing in a MUN as a parameter from a report prompt. For this I recommend creating a Calculated Member via the Query Calculation toolbox object. The expression should simply be

```
[DS_PC_Mayorista].[Delegado Comercial].[Delegado Comercial]->?DELEGADO?
```

The effect would be the same as if you had drug over a member from the source hierarchy. The difference in this case is that the member will be supplied by the prompt instead of being hard-coded.

Comment: I tried what you comment, but the report. I define a Calculated Member with that expression, and instead of filtering in the Detail Filter or the Slicer I create tuples with the prompt value and the measures.
But the report still slow...
Does exist any way to make a report faster using filters?

Comment: You don't have to create tuples. You only have to include the new calculated member in your crosstab, most likely on an edge (e.g. row or column). As for performance, troubleshooting performance issues via this site would be very difficult as there are too many unknown factors. I'm sorry I can't help you with that.